# draw graph showing an electrical event

Tags: tikz-pgf

Can you help me to plot this graph?

[image]

Comment: Do you know the mathematical function that produces such a graph?

Comment: No, I dont know the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I removed one of the zeros in the axis

```
\documentclass[border = 5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[-latex, thick, black] (0, 0) node[left]{$0$} -- (2 * pi, 0) node[right]{$t$};
  \draw[-latex, thick, black] (0, -2) -- (0, 2) node[left]{$E$};
  \draw[thick, black] plot[variable = \x, domain = 0:2*pi, smooth]
    ({\x}, {2 * (1 - exp(-0.6 * pow(\x, 2))) * (1 - exp(-0.6 * pow(\x - 2 * pi, 2))) * sin(\x r)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A `snake` decoration can be used to draw this quite easily.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border = 5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex, thick]
  \draw[->] (0, 0) node[left]{0} -- (2.05*pi, 0) node[right]{$t$};
  \draw[->] (0,-2) -- (0, 2) node[left]{$E$};
  \draw [decorate,decoration={snake,amplitude=1.7cm,segment length=5.4cm}] (0,0) -- (2*pi,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]